# Fetching data in specific table and insert them in an other table using laravel and eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, loops, for-loop, eloquent

I try to retrieve the information from a table in my database to insert it into another table immediately using a loop for to browse it but it only returns me a single element can help me please to solve this I struggle since a moment.

```
$data = Portefeuille::where("portefeuilles.Cloture", "=", 0)
    ->where("portefeuilles.Octroye", "=", 1)
    ->join('echeanciers', 'echeanciers.NumDossier', '=', 'portefeuilles.NumDossier')
    ->where("echeanciers.DateTranch", "=", $dateDuJour)
    ->where("echeanciers.statutPayement", "=", 0)
    ->where("echeanciers.CapAmmorti", ">", 0)
    ->get();
    
    
    
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) {
     return return response()->json([$data[$i]->NumDossier]);  //gives me only one value however I should get ten values.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are returning a response inside your for loop so on its first iteration it returns the response

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) {
      $response[]= $data[$i]->NumDossier; 
 }
 
return response()->json($response);
```

***Suggestion: Instead of using the `for` loop you can use the `foreach` loop***

```
foreach($data as $item) {
      $response[]= $item->NumDossier; 
 }
 
return response()->json($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need an array of the attribute `NumDossier` and have relations in place, you can do it like this

```
$numDossiers = Portefeuille::query()
    ->whereHas('echeancier', function($echeancier) use($dateDuJour) {
        $echeancier->where('dateTranch', '=', $dateDuJour)
            ->where('statutPayement', '=', 0)
            ->where('CapAmmorti', '>', 0);
    })
    ->where('Cloture', '=', 0)
    ->where('Octroye', '=', 1)
    ->pluck('NumDossier')->toArray();

return return response()->json($numDossiers);
```